# How to use Email-ext and Log Parser (with jelly script) pluins in Hudson/Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, hudson-plugins, logparser, email-ext

How to use Log Parser with Email-ext plugin to get parsed console output via e-mail?

I use `${JELLY_SCRIPT,template="html"}` to get formatted message.

After installing and configuring Log Parser Plugin, I still getting emails with not parsed console output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Console Parser plugin creates separate html files that can later be displayed via a link on build status page. It has nothing to do with Email-ext plugin (at least not directly). There are couple of options as I see it:

- Forget about Log Parser plugin in e-mails. Format the output yourself in the template (for more heavy-duty formatting you can use Groovy script option of EmailExt plugin).
- Provide just a summary in the e-mail and include a link to parsed console output. It's at `http://<jenkins_server>/job/<job-name>/<build-num>/parsed_console`.

As an aside:

Log Parser plugin is a great time-saver when you have huge logs.

In general my experience shows that build e-mails are more of a nuisance than of help: either there are too many so people just ignore them, or too few to be of real service. For some reason managers love them, while developers hate them. I've spent a week creating a super-duper report with EmailExt and Groovy - in the end nobody looks at it. The only e-mails that I find somewhat helpful are those sent to committers who broke the build. In short, make sure not to waste your time on something that looks sexy, but in the end is almost worthless.

Comment: I think parsed_console no longer exists and it is consoleText instead.